# Unable to execute the code written in asmx MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I have used the following code to check whether data exists or not

This is my input design

```
<label>
 @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Username)</label>
<input type="text" id="username" />
 &nbsp;
<label id="UserNameAvailabilityLabel" class="input_text">
</label>
 <span class="input_error">
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Username)
</span>
</label>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var emptyUserNameMessage = 'Please enter the username';
var progressUserNameMessage = 'Checking...';
var availableUserNameMessage = 'Username is available';
var usedUserNameMessage = 'Username has been taken';


$(function () {
    var userNameAvailabilityLabel = $("#UserNameAvailabilityLabel");

    $("#username").blur(function () {
        var userNameTextBox = $("#username");
        var userName = userNameTextBox.val();
        if ($.trim(userName) == '') {
            userNameAvailabilityLabel
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass('required1')
                        .html(emptyUserNameMessage);
        }
        else {
            userNameAvailabilityLabel.html('');
            $("#ProgressDiv").show();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Checkavailability.asmx/CheckUserNameAvailability',
                data: '{userName: \'' + userNameTextBox.val() + '\'}',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: OnCheckUserNameAvailabilitySuccess,
                error: OnCheckUserNameAvailabilityError
            });
        }
        return false; //Prevent postback
    });

    function OnCheckUserNameAvailabilitySuccess(response) {
        $("#ProgressDiv").hide();
        if (response != null && response.d != null) {
            var data = response.d;
            switch (data) {
                case 0:
                    userNameAvailabilityLabel
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass('available')
                        .html(availableUserNameMessage);
                    $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr('disabled');
                    break;
                case 1:
                    userNameAvailabilityLabel
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass('used')
                        .html(usedUserNameMessage);
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    function OnCheckUserNameAvailabilityError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

This works when I used this in a normal `aspx` page but when coming to `MVC` the first script is getting executed means if I move from text box with out entering data it is displaying the error as per required, if enter some text and leave the text box  it is giving an popup as Internal server error what might be the problem

Comment: We need more information on the error.

Comment: There is nthng much i can share what ever I code I posted

Comment: solved change this `url: 'Checkavailability.asmx/CheckUserNameAvailability',` to `url: '../Checkavailability.asmx/CheckUserNameAvailability'`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just changed `url: 'Checkavailability.asmx/CheckUserNameAvailability',` to `url: "../Checkavailability.asmx/CheckUserNameAvailability",`

Comment: @rhalbersma It's the OP who is giving the answer that worked for him.